# Showing that a linear map $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is an isomorphism.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $t_1,t_2,t_3$ be distinct real numbers and consider the linear map

$$T : \mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3, \quad \quad p(x) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}p(t_1)\\p(t_2)\\p(t_3)\end{pmatrix}$$

I want to show that $T$ is an isomorphism. Since it is given that $T$ is linear, I just need to show that $T$ is bijective. My initial approach was to solve the system

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a + bt_1 + ct_1^2\\
a + bt_2 + ct_2^2\\
a + bt_3 + ct_3^2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
r_1\\
r_2\\
r_3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

for $a,b,c$ in terms of $r_1,r_2,r_3$, thus determining the inverse map $T^{-1}$ mapping a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to a polynomial of degree $\leq 2$.

I solved this system using Maple, and got a solution which was defined when $t_1,t_2,t_3$ where not all equal, which is fine by their definition, but I am wondering if there is a nicer argument, especially since the solution is rather ugly.

(this is not homework)

Comment: Personally, I find the answer by Yuki most intuitive, and understandable. By considering the current votes, it seems like the majority disagrees (though only slightly). I can't find a question on meta about this "dilemma".

Comment: You should accept the answer *you* consider most helpful. If anyone stumbles into this question, he will be able to see the one with the top score (or next-to-top score, if the accepted answer is the top-scoring one) right below the accepted one anyway.  There are even badges here for having nonaccepted answers with higher scores than accepted ones. ;) Personally, I find Jacob Schlather's suggestion to be the most elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$T$ is onto: [Langrange Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Injectivity: if $p$ is an polynomial of degree $\le2$, knowing values in 3 distinct points, you know $p$.

Answer (score 4):

Just take $1,x,x^2$. They transform into $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}t_1\\ t_2 \\ t_3\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}t_1^2\\ t_2^2 \\ t_3^2\end{pmatrix}$. To show that they are linearly independent, calculate the determinant of $\begin{pmatrix}1&t_1&t_1^2\\1&t_2& t_2^2 \\1&t_3& t_3^2\end{pmatrix}$, which is, incidentally, [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: The result heavily used here, and a rather important one, is: an operator $\,T:V\to V\,\,\,,\,\,V\,$ a vector space, is an isomorphism iff the image of some basis is again a basis (or more general: the image of any linearly independent is again lin. indep.) +1

Comment: @DonAntonio: Not really: rather than using the result, I've explicitly shown that it is of rank 3. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint: What is in the kernel of your map?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be easier to show that the associated matrix always has non-zero determinant. This is a [known result](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).